# Replace variable by another variable in PHP

Tags: php, variables, syntax

Here is my situation, let's say i have two variables:

```
$a = "Peter";
$b = "tall";
```

Then, i can combine this by

```
$c = " $a is very $b ";
```

which give me the string : "Peter is very tall"

However, if i have another variable $e passed to my function, and the string is " $a is very $b "
then, i print out $e, it just show me " $a is very $b ";

What i expected is "Peter is very tall", because $e is equal to $c.

This is the whole logic flow:

```
$e = " $a is very $b ";
getMsg($e);
function getMsg($e){
  $a = "Peter";
  $b = "tall";
  $c = " $a is very $b ";
  echo $c //Peter is very tall
  echo $e //$a is very $b
}
```

How can i achieve this function?

Comment: Where's the function that you tried?

Comment: Turn on error reporting and you will see something like `Notice: Undefined variable: a in ... ` and `Notice: Undefined variable: b in ... `. `$a` and `$b` are undefined in your `$e` line. And `echo $e` will probably output " is very ". (Also, your `echo`s are missing a `;`) https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: You should never use double quotes for string, always single ones.
If you try to rewrite your code without double quotes and concatenate strings by yourself, I think you will easily find what's wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `sprintf` [sprintf documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php). The `%s` symbols are string tokens that get substituted in the format string (the 1st param to sprintf).

```
$e = "%s is very %s";
getMsg($e);
function getMsg($e){
  $a = "Peter";
  $b = "tall";
  echo sprintf($e, $a, $b);
}
```

Or a less coupled version of the `getMsg()` function:

```
function getMsg($msg,$name,$is){
  echo sprintf($msg, $name, $is);
}  
getMsg("%s is very %s", "Peter", "tall");
```

Comment: You should never use double quotes for string, always single ones. That's what caused OPs confusion in the first place

Comment: Not always. e.g. `$a='hello'; echo '$a'`

Comment: Yes, that the whole point : that makes you think about if you need quotes or not. You can't just use them everywhere. In that exemple you absolutely don't need quotes, simple or double ones !

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code. I hope this is what you want.

```
<?php
// Your code here!
 $a = "Peter";
  $b = "tall";
$e = $a."is very".$b;
getMsg($e,$a,$b);
function getMsg($e,$a,$b)
{
 $c = $a."is very".$b;
  echo $c;
 echo $e;
}
?>
```

Comment: You need to check the scope of variables and also you need to check you function definition and how you're calling your function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It should work fine. You need to Define `$a` and `$b` outside the function.

```
function getString($a,$b,$e){

  $c = " $a is very $b ";
  echo $c;
  echo '<br/>'.$e;
}
$a = "Peter";
$b = "tall";
$e = " $a is very $b ";
$response = getString($a,$b,$e);
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Peter is very tall 
Peter is very tall
```